# Inserting values in a new column depending on values in existing column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, toad

Say I've two columns A and B

I want to update contents in column B by pulling the data from column A as under; column B is blank as of now

Column A

```
A
C00
C00 Law Firm
C00
C00 Law Firm
C00
M00 Federal Government'
```

Desired Column B

```
B
C00
Q00
C00
Q00
C00
M00
```

and if A has any other value that I don't specify in the update statement then B should have 'Q00' as its corresponding value.

I tried

`If table.a like '%M00'
UPDATE table
set table.b= 'M00' else 'Q00'`

and

`UPDATE table set table.b= 'A00' 
WHERE table.a like '%A00' 
else 'Q00';`

but they don't work

Comment: What do you mean with "that I dont specify" ? you may want to post what you hav e tried so far. please show your UPDATE statement.

Comment: I tried

`If table.a like '%M00'
UPDATE table
set table.b= 'M00' else 'Q00'`


but this doesn't work


By "I don't specify' I mean that if say I'm updating multiple values and I miss and/or deliberately don't specify some values of "a" in the update statement then the corresponding value in B should be Q00

Comment: tried the below query as well

`UPDATE table


set table.b= 'A00'
 WHERE table.a like '%A00' 
else 'Q00';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a transaction for more than one update query

```
    BEGIN;
    update table set b = table.a where a like '%MOO';
    update table set b = 'QOO' where a not like '%MOO';
    COMMIT;
```

Comment: Than You;
 I wish to update multiple values values say B00 for %B00, C00 for %C00 can I place them one below the other to update ?

Comment: Yes you can. Please upvote mark as answered if your question has been answered.

Comment: Getting this error for the above query
`PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with <an identifier>`

Comment: The syntax can differ slightly depending on what you are using to run sql. What are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample, update accordingly to fit your needs:

```
update Table1
SET
col2 = CASE WHEN col1 like '%1%' THEN col1
else '2222'
END
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !
is it possible to add multiple updates to it ?

Comment: @DollarVora that query will update ALL records in the table, with either one value. but all rows none the less.

Comment: I mean can I have
`update Table1
SET
col2 = CASE WHEN col1 like '%1%' THEN col1
else when col1 like '%2%' THEN 'some value'
END`